# Does MongoDB stages should avoid FETCH when INDEX is matching?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

According to the docs, MongoDB should skip the FETCH stage when an index covers a query.

If I correctly understood, this sentences explain this behavior:

> Covered Queries When an index covers a query, MongoDB can both match
> the query conditions and return the results using only the index keys;
> i.e. MongoDB does not need to examine documents from the collection to
> return the results.
>
> When an index covers a query, the explain result has an IXSCAN stage
> that is not a descendant of a FETCH stage, and in the executionStats,
> the totalDocsExamined is 0.
>
> In earlier versions of MongoDB, cursor.explain() returned the
> indexOnly field to indicate whether the index covered a query.
> (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/)

And this

> With this in place, the query takes less than 2 Ms. Because the index
> ‘covered’ the query, MongoDB was able to match the query conditions
> and return the results using only the index keys; without even needing
> to examine documents from the collection to return the results. (if
> you see an IXSCAN stage that is not a child of a FETCH stage, in the
> execution plan then the index ‘covered’ the query.) (https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/mongodb-index-strategy/)

But in a test scenario it doesn't occur:

Example to test:

```
    db.Test.insert({"Field1":"data on field1: 1","Field2":"data on field2: 1"});
    db.Test.insert({"Field1":"data on field1: 2","Field2":"data on field2: 2"});
    db.Test.insert({"Field1":"data on field1: 3","Field2":"data on field2: 3"});
    db.Test.insert({"Field1":"data on field1: 4","Field2":"data on field2: 4"});
    db.Test.insert({"Field1":"data on field1: 5","Field2":"data on field2: 5"});
    db.Test.insert({"Field1":"data on field1: 6","Field2":"data on field2: 6"});
```

After I created an index to Field2.

```
db.Test.createIndex({"Field2":1})
```

And then I query the collection:

```
db.Test.find({"Field2":"data on field2: 5"}).explain("executionStats");
```

I expected a stage `IDXSCAN` that isn't child of a `FETCH` stage. But the output is like this:

```
[...]
"winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "Campo2" : 1.0
                },
                "indexName" : "Field2_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "Campo2" : []
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "Field2" : [ 
                        "[\"data on field2: 5", \"data on field2: 5\"]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
[...]
```

There are two stages: one **"stage" : "FETCH",** and its child **"stage" : "IXSCAN",**.

Can anyone explain what I am misunderstanding?

*** ABOUT PROJECTION

When running query with projection

```
"winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "PROJECTION",
            "transformBy" : {
                "Campo2" : 1.0
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "Field2" : 1.0
                    },
                    "indexName" : "Field2_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "Campo2" : []
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "Field2" : [ 
                            "[\"data on field2: 5", \"data on field2: 5\"]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

With Adam's answer: it worked!

I realized that projection shouldn't include "_id" to avoid `FETCH`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query doesn't specify a [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/), meaning that it will return all fields in the document. This means that the `{ Field2: 1 }` index does not cover the query, since it only contains a single field.

The following query should be fully covered and should not have a FETCH stage. Note that the projection is explicitly excluding the `_id` field, as this [will be included in the projection unless specified otherwise](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#suppress-id-field):

```
    db.Test.find(
      {"Field2":"data on field2: 5"},
      {"Field2" : 1, "_id" : 0 }
    ).explain("executionStats");
```

Output:

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "foo.Test",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "Field2" : {
                "$eq" : "data on field2: 5"
            }
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "PROJECTION",
            "transformBy" : {
                "Field2" : 1,
                "_id" : 0
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "Field2" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "Field2_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "Field2" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "Field2" : [
                        "[\"data on field2: 5\", \"data on field2: 5\"]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 1,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 1,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 0,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "PROJECTION",
            "nReturned" : 1,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
            "works" : 2,
            "advanced" : 1,
            "needTime" : 0,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 0,
            "restoreState" : 0,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "transformBy" : {
                "Field2" : 1,
                "_id" : 0
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 1,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "works" : 2,
                "advanced" : 1,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 0,
                "restoreState" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "Field2" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "Field2_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "Field2" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "Field2" : [
                        "[\"data on field2: 5\", \"data on field2: 5\"]"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined" : 1,
                "seeks" : 1,
                "dupsTested" : 0,
                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0
            }
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
    ...
    },
    "ok" : 1,
    ...
}
```

Comment: I thought that, but not. 
The output when query has projection:
"stage" : "PROJECTION",
...
 "stage" : "FETCH", // [NOT CHILD]
 "stage" : "IXSCAN", // [CHILD]

Comment: are you using any collations?

Comment: @Rafael, did you run the same query with 'executionStats' that Adam provided?

Comment: Thanks... it worked

I realized that projection shouldn't include "_id" to avoid FETCH.

Comment: Now it becomes clearly... the index hasn't "_id", then it won't be covered.

Comment: Great! I just updated my answer to explicitly call out the need to suppress the _id field.

Comment: How does the same work in case of an aggregation? @AdamHarrison can you tell me how can I achieve the same in an aggregation?

Comment: @Temp O'rary - Indexes can also cover an aggregation pipeline, see the 'Changed in version 3.2' note here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes. It will be required to use $project to exclude the `_id` field.

Comment: This I noticed that improves the match and project pipelines but not group or fetch pipelines. How can we optimize group pipeline then?